# Override global variable in LESS css using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I have created a global variable in LESS css and assigned it a value. I used that value in multiple classes in CSS. I want to override that global variable dynamically through javascript.

```css
@color: #f938ab;

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: @color;
}
```

Can I override above variable using JavaScript code or something like below?

```
var color = //color from database;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('@color', color);
```

Or is there any other method in CSS?

Comment: You cannot amend a CSS pre-processor variable in JS. What you are attempting to do is not possible.

Comment: I have used :root css but its not supported for IE browser

Comment: Any other way to change @color value dynamically

Comment: You only can override css by set style by js

Comment: I am having multiple classes where I have to change the color property

Comment: @BaluKhengat not dynamically from JS, no

Comment: I am fetching color value from database and want to set in css at multiple classes

Comment: You asked the same thing about SASS yesterday....

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually, the documentation seems to allow run-time modification of Less variables with javascript http://lesscss.org/3.x/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modify-variables

Comment: @AllanRaquin I stand corrected, but to make that work you need to run LESS on the client which pretty much defeats all benefits of having a CSS pre-compiler

Answer (score 2):

You need to rethink your approach.

Maybe you could apply a class to the main container (`body`?) and change your css to apply specific colours depending on that class? You could possibly update the value of this colour dynamically.

Also, depending on where you compile your LESS file you might have some more options. If you compile it serverside on every request (bad approach) and you read the DB on serverside too than you could change the value of this variable just by altering the file.

If you generate the CSS on client side (bad approach) you could possibly do a similar thing.

Both solutions are quite bad and 'hacky' and would heavily impact the perfomance

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/3.x/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modify-variables):

### Modify Variables

*Enables run-time modification of Less variables. When called with new values, the Less file is recompiled without reloading. Simple basic usage:*

```
less.modifyVars({
  '@buttonFace': '#5B83AD',
  '@buttonText': '#D9EEF2'
});
```

This assumes that you use less on the client side, otherwise you will need to create one css class per color and switch it with javascript.
But the last solution is only possible if you have a specific list of possible color because hexadecimal handle 16 777 216 different one.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add dynamic class on the body and change the value of @color based on the class added on the body and then compile the LESS into css.

```
@color: #f938ab;

body.class1{
@color: color1;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: @color;
}
```

and add the class on body using javascript.